# Partial view with @HTML.Action(...)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a strongly typed partial view that should show the name of an account that a user is logged into:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.AccountNameViewModel

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Action("AccountName", "AccountNameController", Model)
    Logged in to @Model.AccountName
}
```

I have a controller:

```
public class AccountNameController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult AccountName(AccountNameViewModel model)
    {
        ... Do somthing with the repository to populate the model
        return PartialView(model);

    }
}
```

What I want to do is add a shared partial view that displays the name of an account that a user is logged into.  What I get is the following error:

```
The controller for path '/ParentViewPath/' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Am I at least heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to remove the `controller` part in your call

```
 @Html.Action("AccountName", "AccountName", Model)
```

To render a partial view you can also call

```
 @Html.Partial("AccountName", "AccountName", Model)
```