# How to render partial view for HighCharts and pass parameter in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have been able to make a bar chart using DotNet Highcharts pulling from a database. I have modified it to use a viewmodel based on what I read about partial views. I need to be able to pass an id when rendering the partial view. Whenever I try to get the partial view to render, I either get nothing but whitespace, whitespace plus a lone semicolon, or an error about converting void to object or converting anonymous to object.

Here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult ManaProduction(int deckid = 0)

        {

            var query = string.Format("Select C.* from Cards C Left Join CardDecks CD ON CD.CardID = C.CardID Where DeckID = {0}", deckid);
            var cardlist = db.Cards.SqlQuery(query).ToList();
            var red = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesRedMana == true).Count();
            var blue = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesBlueMana == true).Count();
            var green = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesGreenMana == true).Count();
            var white = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesWhiteMana == true).Count();
            var black = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesBlackMana == true).Count();
            var colorless = cardlist.Where(g => g.ProducesColorlessMana == true).Count();
            Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
                .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
                .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Mana Production" })
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "White", "Black", "Colorless" } })
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                {
                    Min = 0,
                    Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Mana Count" }
                })
                .SetLegend(new Legend
                {
                    Layout = Layouts.Vertical,
                    Align = HorizontalAligns.Left,
                    VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
                    X = 100,
                    Y = 70,
                    Floating = true,
                    BackgroundColor = new BackColorOrGradient(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")),
                    Shadow = true
                })              
                .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = @"function() { return ''+ this.y +': '+ this.x +' mana'; }" })
                .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                {
                    Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
                    {
                        PointPadding = 0.2,
                        BorderWidth = 0,
                        ColorByPoint = true,
                        //Colors =  [ "red", 'blue', 'green', 'gray', 'black', 'gray']

                    }

                })
                .SetSeries(new[]
                {
                    //new Series { Name = "Mana", Data = new Data(new object[] { blue, black, green, white, colorless, red }) },
                     new Series { Name = "Mana", Data = new Data(new[] 
                     {
                      new Point { Y = red, Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed },
                      new Point { Y = blue, Color = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue },
                      new Point { Y = green, Color = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen },
                      new Point { Y = white, Color = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat },
                      new Point { Y = black, Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black },
                      new Point { Y = colorless, Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray }
                     }
                     )},

                });
            var vm = new ViewDeck();
            vm.ManaGraph = chart;
            return View(vm);
```

Here is my view model:

```
public class ViewDeck
    {
public DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts ManaGraph { get; set; }
public Deck Deck { get; set; }
//OTHER PROPERTIES
  public ViewDeck ()
        {  }
}
```

Here are some things I have tried to get the partial view to render:

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("ManaProduction", "Deck", new { deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID });} 

           @{Html.RenderPartial("ManaProduction", new { deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID });}


          @Html.Partial("ManaProduction", new {deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - 
Here is the code for my partial view:

```
@model Login.Models.ViewDeck

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mana Production";
}

@(Model.ManaGraph)
```

Here is the view I am trying to add a partial view to:

```
@model Login.Models.ViewDeck

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Deck.Title)</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Deck</legend>
      <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Deck", new { id = Model.Deck.DeckID })" class="sublink"> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/icons/edit.png") " style="border:none" /> Deck Details</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Deck", new { deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID })" class="sublink">  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/icons/add.png") " style="border:none" />Cards to Deck</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("BasicLand", "Deck", new { deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID })" class="sublink">  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/icons/add.png") " style="border:none" />Basic Lands to Deck</a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Deck", new { deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID })" class="sublink">  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/icons/delete.png") " style="border:none" /> Deck</a><br />
    <div id="tabs">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">View Cards</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Deck Stats</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5">Comments</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
     <hr />TOTAL CARDS IN DECK: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CardCount) || RATING @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Deck.Rating) out of 5 <hr />
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">  <div id='pie_container'>
       @(Model.Chart)</div></div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">    CREATURES(@(Model.CreatureCount))<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Creatures)
         {
            @item<br />
         }
         <br />PLANESWALKERS(@(Model.PlaneswalkerCount))<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Planeswalkers)
         {
            @item<br />
         }
          <br />INSTANTS(@(Model.InstantCount))<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Instants)
         {
            @item<br />
         }
         <br />SPELLS(@(Model.SpellCount))<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Spells)
         {
            @item<br />
         }
          <br />LANDS(@(Model.LandCount))<br />
         @foreach (var item in Model.Lands)
         {
            @item<br />
         }</div></div>
</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="display-field">
      <b>Description:</b>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Deck.Description)
    </div>
            </div>

        <div id="tabs-3">
               @foreach (var item in Model.CardList) {
            <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                   <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Card", new { id = item.CardID })"> <img src ="@Url.Content(item.ImageUrl)" style="width:50%; border:none;" alt="image" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "CardDeck", new { cardid = item.CardID, deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID })">  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/icons/delete.png") " style="border:none" />
        <br />Remove Card</a>
                </div>
            </div>
               }
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-4">
             <hr />
         Wins: @(Model.Deck.Wins)<br />
        Losses: @(Model.Deck.Loss)

       <hr />
<ul>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ManaProduction", "Deck", new {deckid = Model.Deck.DeckID})">Mana Production</a></li>
</ul>
          @Html.Partial("ManaProduction", Model)
```

Comment: Updated my answer, please try that out

Comment: Please see my latest comment on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since your view model type is ViewDeck in your partial view, and that appears to be the same model as the view rendering the partial, you just pass in the model itself.

```
//note that you don't need the semicolon here
@Html.Partial("ManaProduction", Model)
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Login.Models.ViewDeck'. I have added the full partial view code.

Comment: I changed as suggested and now it doesn't hit the ManaProduction controller at all and renders nothing, but there is no error. :( I have added the code for the view I am trying to add the partial view to.

Comment: Thats probably because your partial view has the same name as your controller I'm guessing? Does it not render your entire view at all or just not the partial view? Try to rename your partial view from ManaProduction to ManaProductionPartial and update your Html.Partial call.

Comment: That didn't work. I finally moved all the code to the base controller and then did a partial view:    public ActionResult PartialManaProd()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

Comment: It isn't what I wanted, because I was hoping to put the code for each partial view in its own controller.

Comment: Well, that wasn't in your original question. You should edit your question. As for using a partial view from another controller, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350810/partial-view-with-html-action

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't ask the question correctly. I will edit.